# integrate Re$z$ along the square $\{x+iy: \vert x \vert \leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

So I need to integrate Re$z$ along the square $\{x+iy: \vert x \vert \leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1\}$ with counterclockwise direction.

I know Re$z$=$\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}=\frac{x+iy+x-iy}{2}$ = $x$ so am I just breaking up the integral of $x$ along each line segment so I have

$$\oint_{\{x+iy: \vert x \vert \leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1\}} \text{Re}z dz = \int_{1-i}^{1+i}xdx+\int_{1+i}^{-1+i} x dx+\int_{-1+i}^{-1-i}xdx+\int_{-1-i}^{1-i}x dx$$

Does this work? Also, Am I missing a factor of $i$  as $dz = d(x+iy)=i$ ?

Also, sorry if this is a duplicate, I could not find one.

Comment: The second and fourth terms have $dz=dx$ because $dy=0$, just as you've reasoned; but the first and third terms have $dz=idy$ because $dx=0$.

Comment: so am I integrating the first and third terms w.r.t. $y$ and the second and fourth terms w.r.t. $x$? @J.G.

Comment: Yes, and correct accordingly (in each of the four pieces) your bounds and your integrand.

Comment: @AnneBauval so I have that $\oint \text{Re}z dz = \int_{1-i}^{1+i} ix dy+ \int_{1+i}^{-1+i} xdx +\int_{-1+i}^{-1-i} xi dy + \int_{-1-i}^{1-i}xdx = xi(2i)=-2x+ (\frac{x^2}{2})\bigg\vert_{1+i}^{-1+i}+...$

Comment: No. you forgot to correct the bounds of your four integrals, and the integrand in the first and third ones.

Comment: is the integrand in the first and third one just $i$ ? @AnneBauval

Comment: What is the value of the integrand, i.e. of Re(z), in these two integrals?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139279/discussion-between-mymathyourmath-and-anne-bauval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further reference, the conclusion of our chat (+later correction of the LHS) was:
$$\oint_{\{x+iy: x=\pm1,y=\pm1\}} \text{Re}z dz = \int_{-1}^11idy+\int_1^{-1}xdx+\int_1^{-1}(-1)idy+\int_{-1}^1xdx\\=2i+0+2i+0=4i.$$
The final result may also be viewed as a consequence of [Green's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem):
$$\oint_{\{x+iy: x=\pm1,y=\pm1\}}xdx+xidy =\iint_{\{x+iy: \vert x \vert \leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1\}}\left(\frac{\partial xi}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial x}{\partial y}\right) dx\, dy\\=\iint_{\{x+iy: \vert x \vert \leq 1, \vert y \vert \leq 1\}}idx\, dy=4i.$$